# Where can I find documentation about GNU/Linux TTY formatting

Tags: linux, terminal, tty, ansi

On [gnu.org](https://www.gnu.org) site there is [GNU Head that can be display on terminal](https://www.gnu.org/graphics/agnuheadterm.html) it have XTerm compatible (Normal documented ANSI Codes) but it also contain TTY version (it work on Cygwin, didn't test in XTerm or real terminal).

It contain text like:

```
]Pf767676[1;37mâ]Pf9e9e9e[1;37mâ]P7bcbcbc[47m]Pfeeeeee[1;37mâ]
```

it have `\x1b` then `]Pf767676` and then normal `[1;37m` which is documented for instance on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_codes). What is `]Pf767676` and where it's documented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Linux console specifically, there is the **[console_codes(4)](http://linux.die.net/man/4/console_codes)** manual page. It lists the sequences inherited from VT102, ECMA-48, DEC, and several private ones.

For example, all sequences starting with `ESC [` (shorthand `CSI`) are documented under "ECMA-48 CSI sequences"; they also work the same way on *all* terminals (or don't work at all).

On the other hand, `ESC ]` (shorthand `OSC`) sequences are *private* to each terminal, and their documentation in this manpage is scattered in various places; `ESC ] P` is described as:

```
       ESC ]     OSC      (Should be: Operating  system  command)  ESC  ]  P
                          nrrggbb:  set  palette,  with parameter given in 7
                          hexadecimal digits after the final P :-(.  Here  n
                          is  the  color  (0-15),  and  rrggbb indicates the
                          red/green/blue values (0-255).   ESC  ]  R:  reset
                          palette
```

In other words, the sequence `ESC ] P f 767676` makes the 15th color in the pallete to be hexadecimal #767676.

Comment: So in `]Pf767676[1;37m` f (15th) change 46 Cyan background (counting from 30) to #767676 or it set color to pick with that 37?

Comment: @jcubic: In the Linux console, you directly deal only with an 8-color palette, 0–7 mapping to codes `30`–`37`. The other 8 colors are actually used for "bold" versions of the same codes; i.e. `1` + `30` will select the 8th color instead of 0th. Similarly, `1;37` selects the 15th color. (There exist sequences for a true 16-color palette, but they aren't widely supported, and usually not in terminals that allow modifying the palette at all.)